# How to get GPS coordinates in unity 3d

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gps

I got this code for getting the GPS coordinates but somehow I only got an output of the same coordinates. IT does not change the output where ever I go and sometimes I got 0 for latitude and 0 for longtitude as output please someone help me or someone have a syntax in getting the coordinates

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class testlocation : MonoBehaviour {

    public void Start()
    {

        // turn on location services, if available 
        Input.location.Start();
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        Text singleText = GameObject.Find("SinglePlayerButton").GetComponentInChildren<Text>();

        //Do nothing if location services are not available
        if (Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
        {
            float lat = Input.location.lastData.latitude;
            float lon = Input.location.lastData.longitude;



            singleText.text = "Depart lat: " + lat + "lon: " + lon;

        }
        else
            singleText.text = "gps off";
    }



}
```

Comment: Try checking the status. Does that reveal any issues? And keep in mind that default update distance is 10 meters. If you're not moving more than that, you many not get any new results.

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure the GPS is enable and there aren't any runtime errors in your code, it may be the way you're testing.

Input.location.Start() method has a default distance value to be updated. by default it has 10m, thus you need to walk 10m to see the changes. Change those values at the moment of initialitation.

Input.location.Start(10,0.1f); // accuracy, every 0.1m